# Using ffmpeg to generate thumbnails every minute at the first frame in the interval

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

Granted, the minute may be different (e.g. 30 seconds or 2 minutes), but the logic of the issue remains the same. I currently have three solutions, all with their own drawbacks.

My first solution uses the fps selection as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf scale=320:-1,fps=1/60 "img%04d.jpg"
```

This goes through the video once, however the selection for the frames isn't the first frame every 60 seconds, but instead the middle frame for them. This produces frames at `0:30`, `1:30`, `2:30`... and so on.

My second solution calculates the number of thumbnails via bash, and uses the `ss` option in order to manually seek the thumbnail and retrieve it:

```
#durRaw: interval in seconds (this case: 60)
#end: the end index for the number of thumbnails needed
for t in $(seq 0 $end)
do
    local time=$(bc -l <<< "(( $t * $durRaw ))")
    ffmpeg -i <input> -ss $time -vframes 1 -vf scale=320:-1 "img$(printf "%04d" $t).jpg"
done
```

This results in accurate frames, but *too many video reads*, as it will generally have to seek through the entire video 30-60 times in order to generate the necessary thumbnails.

Finally, my third solution, which happens to be fast and accurate, suffers from a quality degradation as the video progresses (artifacts will start becoming visible and the filesize drops to about 25% of comparable files). I understand the video is scaled, but the quality drops even further than what I have scaled to. I used the `select` filter and fed the framerate calculation into it:

```
getFrameRate() {
    ffmpeg -i "$1" 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"
}
local fr=$(getFrameRate <input>)
local sel=$(bc -l <<< "(( $fr * $durRaw ))") #in actual code, sel is floored
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "scale=320:-1,select='not(mod(n,$sel))',setpts='N/($fr*TB)'" "img%04d.jpg"
```

[image]

I can't seem to generate thumbnails without having some sort of massive drawback. Due to the number of videos I need to run this through, solution 2 (while being optimal) would take weeks to actually finalize processing for all the videos needed. Solution 3 would be ideal if there was no degradation involved, and online guides seem to all point back to the same solutions I have tried. In short, I need to be able to generate thumbnails reasonably quickly (aka in a single passthrough) without unreasonably losing quality.

Comment: It always seems when writing the problem out, you find something right after posting. [According to this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking), the order in which `ss` is used matters, which might be resultant of why my second solution takes so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-ss` parameter from solution #2 before the input (`-i`), in order to read the input much faster. As an excerpt:

`ss` before:

> The input will be parsed using keyframes, which is *very fast*.

`ss` after:

> Here, the input will be decoded (and discarded) until it reaches the position given by -ss. This will be done *very slowly*

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Took the time to generate information from a matter of minutes/hours to milliseconds/seconds.