# ffmpeg convert MJPEG to H.265

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, h.265

I want use ffmpeg to encode MJPEG -> h265. I need use some thread amount. For example 10 threads.

But my code use all cores of my CPU... Why it ignore [numa-pools](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#cmdoption-pools)?

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i v.raw -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 outf.mp4 -x265-params numa-pools="10"
```

ffmpeg says:

```
...
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 16 threads
...
```

It is true. I also can see that all my cores are busy in htop.

This code use all cores of my CPU too...

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -threads 1  -i v.raw -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 outf.mp4 -x265-params numa-pools="10"
```

$ ffmpeg --version

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
```

I have raw MJPEG video file. 3840x2160, 25fps, YUYV 4:2:2. I got it this way. (Now I set stream-count=2 to decrease size of my file for users, usually I set 1000)

```
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=3840,height=2160,pixelformat=MJPG --stream-mmap --set-parm=25 --stream-to=v.raw --stream-count=2
```

Here you can download [v.raw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_14U6RVBz2OEKropCfjlBTCKP7qVFjso/view?usp=sharing)

P.S. I also try drop ffmpeg and use x265 cli directly, but... What is outf.hevc? No one player can open this...

```
x265 --input v.raw --fps 25 --input-res 3840x2160 --output outf.hevc
```

Comment: ffmpeg arguments can often be [order-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163271/using-ffmpeg-to-generate-thumbnails-every-minute-at-the-first-frame-in-the-inter) (it's essentially a pipeline declaration). Try putting `-x265-params numa-pools="10"` directly after the `-c:v libx265`. A good rule of thumb: arguments before `-i input` are for the `input` file, and arguments before `output.ext` are for the `output` file.

Comment: @Rogue ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -threads 1  -i v.raw -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -x265-params numa-pools="10" -vtag hvc1 f25_1000.mp4 says "x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 10 threads". It works. Great thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg arguments can often be [order-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163271/using-ffmpeg-to-generate-thumbnails-every-minute-at-the-first-frame-in-the-inter). Right code:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -threads 1  -i v.raw -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx265 -x265-params numa-pools="10" -vtag hvc1 f25_1000.mp4
```

says
*x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 10 threads*

Thanks user Rogue.